# does $f(x)$ defined by $f(x)=f(x^2)$ must be a constant?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I proved that if $f(x)$ is continuous then it must be a constant. 
But I can't disprove or prove it for non-continuous function.

Answer (score 6):

Try $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is algebraic, $0$ if not.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Robert's answer but perhaps simpler

$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1  \quad x \in [-1,1]\\ 0 \quad\text{ else}\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: You could simplify this even more, by setting $$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1  \quad x =0\\ 0 \quad\text{ else}\end{cases}.
$$